# UK visa "resolved" vs. ready to collect

Tags: visas, uk, south-africa

I have an email regarding my UK visa application with the subject:

Your uk visa application has been resolved

with a tracking number and link to the teleperformance website. The website has the following statuses ticked:

Application Submitted, Transferred for Decision, Received by UKVI

And the following have red dots next to them, I assume this means that they have not taken place:

Decision Made, Ready for Collection, Passport Collected

"Resolved" in the original email sounds like the process is complete, but the website seems to contradict this. Which is accurate?

Comment: What does the subject line of the email say?  And do they give a tracking number?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that "resolved" is just confusing wording and they are not finished with my application.

Someone else who has just been through the process told me he received three emails, the first of which was this one. Another one with wording about a decision being made and a third about it being ready to collect came before the process was completed.